# Fitting point on a Quadric curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, computer-algebra, quadrics

I am working on research project. I am currently using [CloudCompare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CloudCompare) for my project, which calculates the Gaussian curvature and mean curvature to extract the geometric features of the points. I have a set of points (around 10), which I want to be fitted on a quadric surface so that I can calculate Gaussian curvature and geometric features of those points. Are there any books, videos which explains the mathematics behind this?

I have read the paper http://mesh.brown.edu/taubin/pdfs/taubin-pami91.pdf by Taubin, but I dont understand it properly.

Comment: I think that (1) this may not be the best stack exchange site for your question, and (2) you may need to revise it to add more detail. Is it possible to point to a particular parts of the paper you do understand and parts you don't understand but would like to? If so, maybe people could help you here or, more, likely, at math.stackexchange. If you want a general overview on how this software works, possibly people on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloudcompare could help you. Regardless, if asking the same question on multiple site, make sure to add links between them.